# Binding fails for CommandParameter - Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=SnackbarOne'

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a Snackbar and a Button which is inside a StackPanel which is inside a PopupBox. For some reason it seems this configuration does not allow direct binding. I think it's related because the Snackbar is not in the VisualTree but I don't understand it completely to realize how I should fix this.

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="OmniClient.MainWindow" >
    <Grid>
        <materialDesign:PopupBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
               Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignMultiFloatingActionPopupBox}" 
               PlacementMode="TopAndAlignCentres" ToolTipService.Placement="Right" PopupMode="MouseOver">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button ToolTip="Nueva alerta" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SnackbarOne}"
                    Command="{Binding CrearAlertaCommand}" >
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="AlarmPlus" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        </materialDesign:PopupBox>
        <materialDesign:Snackbar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Width="auto" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MessageQueue="{materialDesign:MessageQueue}" x:Name="SnackbarOne" />
    </Grid>
</MetroWindow>
```

The MainWindow assigns its ViewModel on its constructor

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
```

The output shows the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=SnackbarOne'. BindingExpression:Path=IsActive; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

and command receives parameter null when it's triggered.

Comment: The popup has the datacontext...how is it being bound?

Comment: in the constructor `DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel()`

Comment: So the popup is getting its **own** `mainwindow` viewmodel along with the page's? Doesn't that present a problem? Shouldn't they both have the same reference?

Comment: Sorry I may have not been clear. The whole window is the MainWindow which has a ViewModel in its DataContext. The constructor for MainWindow instantiates it's ViewModel and assigns it to the DataContext. I will edit and add the surrounding tags of the Window now.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this way:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference SnackbarOne}}" Command="{Binding CrearAlertaCommand}">
```